# total derivative in $(0,0)$ of $(2xy^2)(x^2+3y^4)$

Tags: derivatives

can anyone help me with the following:

I have to check in which points the total derivative of f exists.
$f(x,y) = \frac{2xy^2}{x^2+3y^4} when (x,y) \ne (0,0) $ and 0 if $(x,y) = (0,0)$

I thought that i only have to check if the total derivative in (0,0) exists because in every other points it should exists?

Therefore we have the following rule:
$lim_{(h1,h2) -> (0,0)} \frac{f(h1,h2)-f(0,0) -(0,0)\cdot\binom{h1}{h2}}{||h1,h2||} = \frac{f(h1,h2)}{||h1,h2||}$

If that is not equal to 0 then the function is not derivative in (0,0), but I can not find any sequence to show that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h_1=t >0$ and $h_2=\sqrt{t}$. Then show that $ \lim_{t \to 0+0} \frac{f(t, \sqrt{t})}{||(t, \sqrt{t})||}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thx. If I take these i finally come to 1/(2*sqrt(t^2+t)) and here the denominator would be 0 if t goes to 0 and therefore it does not exists?

Comment: Yes. $\lim_{t \to 0+0} \frac{f(t, \sqrt{t})}{||(t, \sqrt{t})||}= \infty.$